# Flash Messages don't work during DB transactions in Laravel 5.7 and 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

If I call `DB::beginTransaction()` in a controller but redirect without calling `DB::rollBack()` first, my flash messages don't appear on the new page.

For example, in a shopping cart, I start a transaction but redirect to the payment page when the credit card payment fails.  The payment error doesn't appear unless I call `DB::rollBack()` first.

This happens on both Laravel 5.7 and 5.8.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

This fails:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

return redirect("/checkout/payment")->withInput($request->all())->withFlashDanger("Credit Card Number is required.");
```

This works:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

DB::rollBack();

return redirect("/checkout/payment")->withInput($request->all())->withFlashDanger("Credit Card Number is required.");
```

I'm thinking this is a bug since there's nothing in the documentation about any correlation between database transactions and flash messages.  I know that adding the `rollBack()` call works, but I don't know if that's the intention or not.

Obviously, calling `rollBack()` is the right thing to do, but I discovered this issue as I was writing the code.

Comment: There's no issue, you simply need to rollBack and that's it. Since you already forgot to do it, use Laravel's `DB::transaction(function() { });` which will take care of rollback and commit for you automatically. Then you can continue to write code as if nothing's happening and there's no transactional system you need to account for.

Comment: I agree that you should always rollback on failure, but my question is if this is a bug, because I wouldn't think database functions should be tied to session data such as flash messages.